# Java SWT remove spacing of parent

Tags: java, layout, swt

Anyone an idea on how to remove the spacing between the parent and the parents content?

e.g.:

> ```
> GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
> layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
> layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
>
> shell.setText("Layout");
> shell.setMaximized(true);
> shell.setImage(imghandler.getCornerimg());
> shell.setLayout(layout);
>       
> Composite mainComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
> data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
> layout.numColumns = 2;
> mainComp.setLayout(layout);
> mainComp.setLayoutData(data);
> mainComp.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
>
> Composite subComp1 = new Composite(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
> data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
> layout.numColumns = 1;
> subComp1.setLayout(layout);
> subComp1.setLayoutData(data);
> subComp1.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
>
> Composite subComp2 = new Composite(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
> data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
> subComp2.setLayout(layout);
> subComp2.setLayoutData(data);
> subComp2.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
>
> Composite subComp3 = new Composite(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
> data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
> layout.numColumns = 2;
> subComp3.setLayout(layout);
> subComp3.setLayoutData(data);
> subComp3.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_MAGENTA));
>
> shell.pack();
> shell.open();
> ```

[image]

I want to remove the spacing between the shell and the mainComp and between the mainComp and the subComps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the margin height and width in the `GridLayout`:

```
layout.marginWidth = 0;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
```

Note: You should also use a new `GridLayout` for each `Composite`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using Netbeans form designer for this. I have made an example using Netbeans where you will notice the parent panel has a black background and is not visible at all

```
public class GridSpacing extends javax.swing.JPanel {


public GridSpacing() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    pnlParent = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlTurquoise = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlPink = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlGreen = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    pnlParent.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pnlParent.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    pnlTurquoise.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 204));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlTurquoiseLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlTurquoise);
    pnlTurquoise.setLayout(pnlTurquoiseLayout);
    pnlTurquoiseLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlTurquoiseLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    pnlTurquoiseLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlTurquoiseLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    pnlParent.add(pnlTurquoise, gridBagConstraints);

    pnlPink.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlPinkLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlPink);
    pnlPink.setLayout(pnlPinkLayout);
    pnlPinkLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlPinkLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    pnlPinkLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlPinkLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    pnlParent.add(pnlPink, gridBagConstraints);

    pnlGreen.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 51));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlGreenLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlGreen);
    pnlGreen.setLayout(pnlGreenLayout);
    pnlGreenLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlGreenLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    pnlGreenLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlGreenLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    pnlParent.add(pnlGreen, gridBagConstraints);

    add(pnlParent, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlGreen;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlParent;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlPink;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlTurquoise;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

[image]

Comment: That is Swing, the question is about SWT (a completely different GUI)